# Gstreamer queries NVR with wrong startTime having a pattern

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

I'm a newbie in gstreamer and I am trying to query a NVR(Network Video Recorder) to get recorded videos of my rtsp camera. Here is my gst pipeline:

> gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://-NVR ip-:-NVRport-/?uuid=-cameraIP-&startTime=20220823170000000&endTime=20220824080200000"
> ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink

startTime is in the format of: Year-Month-Day-Hour(2 digits)-Minute(2 digits)-Seconds(5 digits)

Here, gstreamer queries the NVR with given startTime and endTime, since there is a timezone difference between my computer and NVR I expect to get the recorded video between startTime + 3 and endTime + 3.

However I get the recorded video starting from startTime + 3 + startTime and ending in endTime + 3.

I am pretty sure that there is no problem with my NVR because the same url given as location here works well with VLC and ffmpeg-ffplay.

Any thoughts?